# The emulator process for AVD was killed in MacBook pro 16 inch

Tags: android, android-studio

Operating system: Mac OS X
10.15.6 19G73
CPU: amd64
family 6 model 158 stepping 10
12 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
Crash address: 0x0
Process uptime: 6 seconds

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Qaa.png)

Answer (score 2):

go to Android studio tools>SDK Manager>Appearance & Behavior> System Settings>Android SDK and check if Android S Preview is installed, if not Install it. once the installation is done then go to Updates and check for updates and update required packages. which fixed my issue, hope it works for you too.
Thanks
Sandeep